# JSON request to GET HOST list by GroupName

Tags: zabbix

I have Zabbix 3.2.

I want to get HOST List via API by search Group

I found and checked variant by GroupID
For example:

```
zabbix_get= \
        {
            "jsonrpc": "2.0",
            "method": "host.get",
            "params": {
                "output": ["host"],
                "groupids": ["1945"],
            },
            "auth": authToken.get("result"),
            "id": authToken.get("id")
        }
```

Is it possible to search by group name, for example name "Group1"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you cannot filter for group membership in `host.get`, you could use [hostgroup.get](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/api/reference/hostgroup/get) with the `selectHosts` parameter.

Comment: zabbix_get= \
        {
            "jsonrpc": "2.0",
            "method": "hostgroup.get",
            "params": {
                "output": "extend",
                "filter": {
                    "name": [
                        "Group1"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "auth": authToken.get("result"),
            "id": authToken.get("id")
        }

Comment: tryed this variant